# How do I invoke IL2JS correctly?

Tags: c#

I saw that Microsoft open-sourced [IL2JS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/IL2JS), which seems to be a tool to compile Silverlight applications to pure javascript via compiling the IL.

However, I can't seem to get it to work.  When I run:

> PS C:\source\IL2JS-master\bin> ./il2jsr -rewrite C:\FlatRedBallProjects\Test1\Te
>   st1\Test1\Bin\Debug\Test1.dll  -out test.js -reference .\IL2JS_mscorlib.dll

When I run this I get

> error 3003: No assembly name resembled the special 'JSTypes' assembly
>   1 errors, 0 warnings

So I tried to add another -reference option for jstypes and got the following output:

> PS C:\source\IL2JS-master\bin> ./il2jsr -rewrite C:\FlatRedBallProjects\Test1\Test1\Test1\Bin\Debug\Test1.dll  -out test.js -reference .\IL2JS_mscorlib.dll -reference  .\IL2JS_JSTypes_silverlight.dll
>
> error 3005: Unable to load assembly from file 'C:\source\IL2JS-master\bin': cannot load mscorlib
>   1 errors, 0 warnings

So it seems like you can only have one -reference option, but you need to somehow reference both jstypes and mscorlib assemblies.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit**: 
So after some more debugging it seems like the correct way to do this is to use 2 -reference arguments.  The reason why the latter doesn't work is because of

```
        CCI.SystemTypes.Initialize(false, true, ResolveReference);

        // ----------------------------------------
        // Account for mscorlib being loaded
        // ----------------------------------------
        mscorlib = CCI.SystemTypes.SystemAssembly;
        if (mscorlib == null || mscorlib.Directory == null)
```

In `AssemblyLoader.cs`.  That last if statement fails (`mscorlib.Directory` is null).  Now the question is why...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/IL2JS/blob/master/HOW_TO_BUILD.txt , you need to set the IL2JSROOT environment variable,

"or the registery setting
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IL2JS@Root
   to be set to . The powershell setup above sets this variable for you. If you wish
   to use the solutions or projects elsewhere, please set this variable yourself."

Try that, it may help.